# Count Occurence isn't adding

Tags: java, arrays

I was having trouble with this program that asks me : Write a program that generates 10 integers between 0-9 and displays the the count for each number. I am having trouble on the count occurrence for each of the single digit numbers. It seems my program dosen't add the counter right.  Here is my program:

I've tried to read other code to help fix it but nothing worked.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class CountsArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] list = new int[10];

        int[] num = new int[10];



        for(int i = 0; i< list.length;i++) {

            list[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);



        }

        for(int i = 0; i< list.length;i++) {

            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");

        }

        System.out.println();



        int temp = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <num.length;i++) {

            temp = num[i];

            list[temp]++;

        }

        for(int i = 0;i < list.length;i++) {

            if(list[i]>0 && list[i]==1) {

    System.out.printf("%d occurs %d time\n",i, list[i]);

        }

            else if(list[i] >= 2) {

    System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times \n", i, num);

        }



        }

        }}
```

If the random numbers is : 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
The output should be 1 occured 2 times, 2 occured 3 times, 3 occured 2 times.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way , first since random integers are 0 to 9 so adding 1 to Math.random() will also produce ten which will be wrong as per the question
then increment places in num (that is if you encounter 3 in list then increment num[3] by one as count of 3 is now 1)   as you traverse the list and then print num if num[i]>0 as there might be integers which have not occured at all.

```
`int[] list = new int[10];
    int[] num = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i< list.length;i++) {
        list[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< list.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        ++num[list[i]];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if(num[i]>0){
            System.out.printf("%d occurs %d times\n",i,num[i]);
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to make sure that the numbers were in order (have a look at `Arrays.sort`), and then loop over the array - if the current number is the same as the last, add to a count, or else start a new count for the new number.